# Android Fabric to Firebase migration effects on production app

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have gone through many of the Fabric and Firebase documentation to see what will happen to my production Android app, if I do not migrate or change the Fabric sdk.

If I don't do this, what will be the impact to my app, my users, myself (What Crash information won't I be able to see)

To be more specific:

1. Will the app be removed from the Play Store (Like what has happened for permission changes - I think this is not a serious problem and the app will not be removed)?
2. The app will not report any crash logs in Fabric
3. Is there a way to see the crash logs in Firebase without updating the app?
4. Any other changes I need to know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin from Fabric here!

To answer your questions:

1. We haven't run into anyone having their app removed for permissions reasons after completing the migration - this shouldn't be an issue.
2. After setting up the migration, you will be able to see your Crashlytics information flowing to both your Fabric and Firebase dashboards without any further set up required.

The steps are:

-Make sure you're an admin in Fabric and have the "Owner" role in Firebase
-Head to https://fabric.io/firebase_migration
-Drag the desired Fabric apps to their locations in Firebase
-The apps will be linked and crashes will be viewable in both

3. As long as you continue to update the Crashlytics dependencies as normal you shouldn't see any disruptions to your crash logs in either dashboard as of now.
4. Check out our [roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap) to learn more about migration plans feature rollout.

Comment: Firebase says we need to add Analytics to get full crash logs. My app was not there on Firebase until now, so do i need to add Analytics to my app now ?. To do that I'll have to add google-service.json file too , right ?

Comment: Hi Shahal, that's right you would need to add the google-services.json in order to begin using Analytics. You'll still get the full crash logs without it, but the Analytics integration specifically gives you the "crash-free user" stats and graph on the Crashlytics dashboard that you probably used in Fabric.

Comment: Hi @KevinKokomani will my applications under Fabric crashlytics crash after March 31 if we fail to migrate them? Thanks for the inputs

Comment: Nope! They're designed to fail silently and gracefully in these scenarios.